# Is there String.Split() which takes StringComparison into account?

Tags: .net, string, unicode, equality, case-sensitive

In [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx) we are encouraged to supply proper [`StringComparison`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever we are comparing strings. I agree with the point but I see that unlike other methods, [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) actually does not have overloads with comparison parameter.

**Is there equivalent of `String.Split()` taking string comparisons somewhere in the framework or am I expected to write my own?**

Comment: What option would make sense for `String.Split`? Delimiters typically do *not* have a case. You could argue that using letters as delimiters is a bug. The link you posted talks about comparisons, not splitting. If you want a flexible way to parse strings, it's better to use regular expressions that can match specific cases, accents and character classes.

Comment: It's documented to use the `Ordinal` comparison. Apparently the developers thought that is the only one that makes sense for such method as `Split()`. Probably the only one that makes sense given that the separators list is a `char[]`. `string[]` separators probably follow the same rule for consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing is `Regex.Split`. It can ignore case and culture.
Example: `Regex.Split("FirstStopSecondSTOPThird", "stop", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Will result in:

```
First
Second
Thrid
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there equivalent of `String.Split()` taking string comparisons somewhere in the framework?

No. There is not. And frankly I don't think it makes a lot of sense. If you split a string on a special character, generally because another system supplied the original string to you, why would you want to split on `X` and `x`? Usually you don't want to, and .NET doesn't supply a method to help you with it.

> Am I expected to write my own?

Well, you could use a little help. Here is a case insensitive splitter. It still needs some work, but you can use it as a starting point:

```
public static string[] Split(string s, params char[] delimeter)
{
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();

    int lastPartIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (delimeter.Select(x => char.ToUpperInvariant(x)).Contains(char.ToUpperInvariant(s[i])))
        {
            parts.Add(s.Substring(lastPartIndex, i - lastPartIndex));

            lastPartIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }

    if (lastPartIndex < s.Length)
    {
        parts.Add(s.Substring(lastPartIndex, s.Length - lastPartIndex));
    }

    return parts.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Accidentally found that [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) already provides the required functionality.

Comment: Thank you for clear `No. There is not.`. Also thanks for effort to show the way. Personally I will probably go with `IndexOf()` and without Linq. But maybe some readers will be happy with the above approach.